# PTIJ: What dummy is the Gemara referring to?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

We find in many places throughout shas we find the words of

> היכי דמי

I was always confused by this statement. Who is this dummy, and why is the Gemara mentioning him?

Thanks.

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: I don't suppose Dummy Ben Nesina would be an appropriate answer.

Comment: Not only דמי, but also cousins דמיא and דמיין

Comment: JSYK the policy is not to include tags besides PTIJ.

Comment: There was this one Amora who didn't understand לבוד, they kept yelling at him "it's לבוד, dummy" (כלבוד דמי).   The name eventually stuck.

Answer (score 19):

In Genesis 4:10 we have the following verse:

> ויאמר מה עשית קול דמי אחיך צעקים אלי מן האדמה
>
> And he said: "What have you done? The voice of Dummy your brother is crying out to me from the ground."

From this verse we can derive two things about Dummy:

1. He is your brother.
2. He is trapped in the ground.

Who do we know that was trapped in the ground?

Korach!

But if Dummy is Korach, we must ask in what sense is he "your brother"?

Well what else do we know about "your brother"?

In Genesis 37:13 we find out that "your brother" is a shepherd:

> הלא אחיך רעים בשכם
>
> Is not your brother shepherding in Shechem?

And what do we know about a shepherd? Well the Mishnah in Bava Kamma 6:1 says:

> נכנס הרואה תחתיו
>
> The shepherd replaces him.

What was Korach's agenda? To replace Moshe.

**Thus, Dummy = your brother = shepherd = Korach.**

Now you might ask why some of these verses appear to use the plural form (e.g. צעקים, רעים) if they are talking about one person, namely Dummy. The answer to that lies in a Talmudic statement in Zevachim 43b:

> ונאמרו קדשים בלשון רבים
>
> And the holy ones are said in plural form.

And what was Korach's mantra? We find it in Numbers 16:3:

> כל העדה כלם קדשים
>
> The entire congregation is all holy ones.

So of course Korach (Dummy) would be referred to in the plural form!

Comment: *slow clap* Well done.

Comment: @Alex, great answer. However, you didn't answer the 2nd part of my question, why is the Gemara talking about this dummy?

Answer (score 3):

Baruch Shekivanta!  That is indeed the question of the Gemara:

> היכי דמי
>   Who is the dummy?

Comment: Isn’t that the point of the OP’s question? What’s the answer to the Gemara’s question?

Answer (score 2):

A dummy in English is what is known as a [pacifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pacifier) in American. In Hebrew it is called a [מוצץ](https://he.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A6%D7%A5).

So it is obvious that the dummy/pacifier/*motzetz* mentioned everywhere by the gemara is none other than Aharon.

After all, Rambam in [Ma'amar Kiddush Hashem](https://www.sefaria.org/Iggerot_HaRambam%2C_Maamar_Kiddush_HaShem?vhe=Kobetz_Teshuvot_HaRambam,_1859&lang=bi) quotes the following *midrash*:

> ואהרן מוצץ
>
> And Aharon is a *motzetz*.

This fits with what we know of Aharon's character from [Avot deRabbi Natan 12:3](https://www.sefaria.org/Avot_D'Rabbi_Natan.12.3?lang=bi), namely that he would pacify the parties to an argument until they made peace.

Comment: I'm sure this is מציצה בפה